# Run batch file from Cygwin with default Windows login environment

Tags: windows, batch-file, cygwin

I know this is a bit of an edge case but does anybody know why the following line from a batch script doesn't work executed from Cygwin:

```
@DIR "c:\" | FIND "bytes free" > .batch.temp
```

the same works from the command line in windows

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Is there any way to start a batch file from Cygwin with the default windows login environment and wait for its execution? I only found a solution starting the explorer.exe but then I can't pass arguments to the bat file and I can't wait for the execution.

```
 cmd /c start /b /wait "C:\Windows\explorer.exe" ...
```

**EDIT2**

I use a workaround now because the script I am calling is just incompatible with find.exe from POSIX so I do:

```
TEMP_PATH=$PATH
PATH=`echo $PATH | sed -e "s/:\/usr\/bin//g"`
eval $job

# Restore full POSIX
PATH=$TEMP_PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

because it executes the linux `find` command that works in a different way. Try to call `%windir%\System32\find.exe`

Comment: Is there a way to start from Cygwin a batch script with arguments in the default windows login environment and wait on the Cygwin console until execution has terminated?